# NSUserDefaults and show a picture

Tags: iphone

iam using setting.bundle and i try to show a hidden picture with Switch toggle , here is my code but i miss something :

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
[//Some code show the hidden pic];   myPic.hidden = NO;
```

my key is .e.g = `wood_back`
should i use `ObjectForKey` ?

//Sound Problem :

now i try to off a sound effect on my app

play method is `[myMusic play];`

```
BOOL soundIsOff = [defaults boolForKey:@"sound_off"];
//the problem is here :D
//xcode compiler doesn't copile this code 

[myMusic play] = soundIsOff
```

sound code :

```
///sound effect
    NSString * musicSonati = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"];
    myMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicSonati] error:NULL];
    myMusic.delegate = self;
    myMusic.numberOfLoops = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a switch toggle you should get the value back using `boolForKey:`.

```
BOOL wood_back = [defaults boolForKey:@"wood_back"];
// do anything with wood_back, e.g.
myPic.hidden = wood_back;
```

Comment: thank you Kenny . Works great :):-* :-X
have you any tutorial with Slider toggle ? :D

Comment: kenny i have another problem ! check the question again !

Comment: @Momeks: Meh, ask a new question!

Comment: here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554905/off-a-sound-effect-with-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 0):

[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] values are not automatically synchronized with the values defined in your Settings.bundle plist files. Check out my detailed [article on how to keep user defaults synched in your app](http://excitabyte.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/keeping-user-defaults-synchronized-with-settings-bundle/).